# How do I delete duplicate values with group by

Tags: mysql

Example database :

```
ID StudentName StudentClass
1  John        A
2  John        B
3  Peter       A
4  John        A
5  John        B
```

I want the result should be

```
ID StudentName StudentClass
1  John        A
2  John        B
3  Peter       A
```

Statment

```
DELETE FROM Student
 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MIN(n.ID)
                            FROM Student n
                        GROUP BY n.StudentName) x)
```

How do I keep **John** name on class **A & B**?

Comment: Add n.StudentClass to the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE a FROM Student a
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT MIN(ID) AS minid
        FROM Student
        GROUP BY StudentName, StudentClass
    ) b ON a.id = b.minid
WHERE
    b.minid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

A better method to disallow even insertion of such duplicates would be multi-column unique index(it will optimize your searches too). Here is how:

```
ALTER TABLE `Student`
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX `idx` (`StudentName`, `StudentClass`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to join `Students` against itself, with a JOIN predicate that ensures the JOIN matches duplicate students, and delete the join'd row:

```
DELETE 
  duplicate_students.* 
FROM Students JOIN Students as duplicate_students 
  ON Students.StudentName = duplicate_students.StudentName
  AND Students.StudentClass = duplicate_students.StudentClass
  AND duplicate_students.ID > Students.ID
```

NOTE: Please back up your data first; I take no responsibility for lost data :-) This is a conceptual idea and has not been tested.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
DELETE S FROM Student S
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID,StudentName,StudentClass FROM Student
    GROUP BY StudentName,StudentClass
) S2 ON S.ID != S2.ID AND S.StudentName = S2.StudentName AND S.StudentClass = S2.StudentClass
```

Its basically selecting the minimum ID out of all the duplicate records in sub query. Then we simply delete everything that matches that Class and Name, But we don't match the Minimum Id, so at end of day, we are keeping (presumably) 1st record out of duplicates and eradicating rest.